# Access list items by name to assign to variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am sure the answer to this is everywhere but I am struggling to find it, perhaps I am not wording it correctly?

I have a list of items as shown:

[image]

What I want to then do is something like:

```
var phoneNo = res("phone_number").Value;
```

But what is the actual syntax?

EDIT:
Here's something I've tried to no success:

[image]

Comment: I've updated my answer to show a new screenshot

Comment: What is the value of `res.First().GetType()`?

Comment: What is the value of `res.Cast<Claim>().Where(z => z.Type == "phone_number").Count()`?

Comment: If res is IEnumerable<Claim>, try var phoneNo = res.Where(c => c.Type == "phone_number").FirstOrDeafult()?.Value;

Comment: @MBakardzhiev Might as well combine `Where` and `FirstOrDefault` - i.e. FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "phone_number")?.Value;

Comment: whoever downvoted the question for the love of god please explain why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the feedback given I would like to show two of the best methods I took away from this.

The method I went with:

```
//set up a dictionary
var claims = ctx.User.ToClaims().ToDictionary(claim => claim.Type, claim => claim.Value);

//access as follows
var phoneNo = claims["phone_number"];
var firstName = claims["given_name"];

//etc.
```

Another good way:

```
//set up IEnumerable
var claims = ctx.User.ToClaims();

//access as follows
var phoneNos = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "phone_number")?.Value;
var firstName = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "given_name")?.Value;

//etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to get value from your claims. You can do so as below:

```
 var userClaims = context.HttpContext.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
```

Get you claim value:

```
 if (userClaims.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "phone_number").FirstOrDefault() != null)
 {
       var phoneNumberClaim = User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "phone_number").FirstOrDefault().Value;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a special structure in programming for such tasks. It is called Dictionary.

I think your `ToClaims` method should return Dictionary, so you can access values by whatever key you want. Also you can cast your list using `.ToDictionary(...)`, where you could split string by `":"` for key and value.